# Joining .synctex files of documents blended by \includepdf

Tags: pdfpages, texworks, forward-inverse-search

When I typeset a journal issue, I first make the seperate articles, and I join them together (adding the Table of Contents and other stuff, that's irrelevant now).

When I read the final `issue.pdf`, I often find small mistakes in the articles. However, the <kbd>Jump to Source</kbd> in context menu in TeXworks brings me only to the instruction `\includepdf` in `issue.tex`, and not to the correct file `a1/art1.tex`.

Is there any way how to correctly join all the `.synctex.gz` files generated by all the articles and the issue itself, so that the forward-inverse-search works as I would like?

I appreciate partial or non-automated solutions and ideas as well.

MWE: File **`issue.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
This is an issue 42 of Journal of funny \TeX\@ questions.\\
Contents:\\
Article One, on page 2\\
Article Two, on page 4
\end{center}

\includepdf[pages=-]{a1/art1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{a2/art2.pdf}

\end{document}
```

MWE: File **`a1/art1.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{ARTICLE ONE}
\setcounter{page}{2}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some text. Some text. Some text.

\newpage
Other page of article one.
\end{document}
```

MWE: File **`a2/art2.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{ARTICLE TWO}
\setcounter{page}{4}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some text. Some text. Some text.

\newpage
Other page of article two.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see easy ways to do it.

Comment: @egreg Well, SyncTeX is able to step in files that are `\input` or `\include`d. So it might be possible to just correctly mix the XML files. After all, I keep, to some extent, the proper page numbering and stuff. I wanted to know whether there's anything done in this direction. If not, I'll consider seeing what can be done.

Comment: I don't think there is anything. But `.synctex` files are not XML.

Comment: Damn, you're again right. I've always thought they are...

Comment: Tom is there any reason that you can't use `combine` or `standalone`?

Comment: Well, there is. Each article is delivered to me from different sources, uses different user-defined macros, and I get them in the form authors prepared them in the class. In the end, I need not only the `issue.pdf`, but the seperate files `art1.pdf` and `art2.pdf` as well. And last, but not least, this is not a crucial feature for me, and I have 60k of code written in the class ;) As for `combine`, especially the `\usepackage` problem is a serious issue here.

Comment: I guess you've thought of this, but what about linking the pages to the pages in the original PDFs from which the `synctex` stuff will presumably work to take you to the relevant bit of the article source? (`pdfpages` offers various options along these lines using `hyperref` which is why I assume you've considered it.)

Comment: @cfr That sounds like an interesting option which would save some time, thanks for that! Still, the solution with joining the synctex files would be even better ;)

Comment: Indeed. But I have no idea either how to do that or whether anybody else knows how to do that, so I suggest it as a potentially-useful stop-gap measure in the case that no knight in shining armour emerges from the field to save the day. (Why anybody should care whether the knight's armour has been polished under the kinds of circumstances knights in shining armour are meant to emerge has never been terribly clear to me. I mean, if you were about to be eaten by a three-headed monster, would you turn down an otherwise competent knight solely because his/her armour was a bit tarnished?)

Comment: We need a script to merge multiple SyncTeX files together. How to find the grammar used in SyncTeX files? (synctex-parser exists on CTAN but it is poorly documented)

Answer (score 4):

This is an algorithm how to generate the desired SyncTeX file. A full implementation is one the way but it will take a while... So for the moment I restrict my answer more or less to the application on the MWE. (A generalization seems possible in the future...)

1. Decompress the needed `synctex` files. The following shell script (save it as `decompress-synctex`) does this.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   SYNCGZ=.synctex.gz
   SYNC=.synctex
   for SFILE; do   # unzipping all files + save main file
       gunzip -c $SFILE$SYNCGZ > $SFILE$SYNC
   done
   cp $1$SYNC $1-orig$SYNC
   cp $1$SYNCGZ $1-orig$SYNCGZ
   ```

   Run it as follows: `./decompress-synctex issue a1/art1 a2/art2`
2. Insert the `Input:` line of `art1.synctex` ending with `art1.tex` e.g.

   ```
   Input:1:/home/tux/testing/a1/./art1.tex
   ```

   in `issue.synctex` after all the `Input:` lines at the beginning but before `Content`. Repeat this step with the other `artX.synctex` files.
3. In every `synctex` file, lines between `{i` until `}i` state the box records of **page** `i`. Such a **box record** line

   (a) consists of "[", "(", "v", "h", "x", "k", "g", "$"  followed by `<input number>`, ",", remaining material, or

   (b) is "]" or ")", or

   (c) starts with "!" and continues with a number (number of byte to get to the *previous* "!").

   Now, the number after the `:` in a inserted `Input:` line has to be changed such that the numbering in *all* `Input:` lines in the entire `issue.synctex` is consecutive. If you change `Input:1:...art1.tex` to `Input:42:...art1.tex`, you also have to change all corresponding box records, that is, `[1,...` becomes `[42,...` but only for those pages (remember `{i` .... `}i`) that belong to `Input:....art1.tex`, and the same goes with "(", "v", "h", "x", "k", "g", "$" boxes.

   Since this is not complicated enough, count the number of replacements in each page, too, (hopefully your editor does this for you while replacing) and add this number to the number after the "!" at the end of a page. If the number of digits increases by k digits, then finally, add k to the number after the next "!".
4. If no mistake is made, you are lucky and the inverse search will work as expected!

Comment: I've started writing a script to automate this algorithm. I'll add it if it is ready.

Comment: Well, without the script, the algorithm is sort-of useless since the purpose is to simplify the forward-inverse-search, which is not done by manually editing files. Anyways, thanks for your input!

Comment: Here is the link: [synctex-inclpdf-alpha.sh](http://pastebin.com/mmwHj6qZ). It is a shell script using awk. There is one restriction, which will be removed later, of course: the file setup must be as in your question except that the file contents can be changed if page breaks remain the same (i.e. same number of pages). After running pdflatex and before opening the issue.pdf the script must be run with
`./synctex-includepdf-alpha.sh issue a1/./art1 a2/./art2`